# The authentication token issued by the Identity service has expired in keystone (Openstack icehouse)

Tags: openstack, keystone, openstack-horizon, juju

I deployed openstack using MAAS-Juju(juju charms). After I tried to login into the openstack horizon I face the following issue.The authentication token issued by the Identity service has expired in keystone (Openstack icehouse)please help.

Comment: It was time sync issue. I synchronized time in all my juju nodes and it worked out fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the time of your machines are in sync.